# Map an environment variable in Github Actions

Tags: github-actions

I created a GitHub Actions Job with a strategy matrix that creates a set of environment variables.
One of them is `machine_architecture` which is either 32 or 64.

In most steps I can use it directly i.e. via `${{ machine_architecture }}`. 
But some steps requires strings like 'i386' vs 'x86_64'. Is there an easy way in github actions to create a map-object that I can use in expressions like:

```
map_object = { 32: "i386", 64: 'x86_64' }
...
${{ map_object[machine_architecture] }}
```

If not, what is the idiomatic way in github actions to solve that problem?

PS: I am aware, that I can [set environment variables in steps](https://help.github.com/en/actions/reference/development-tools-for-github-actions#set-an-environment-variable-set-env), but the problem is, that these variables are only available for the following steps (i.e. not for usage in "run-on:" tag)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

In the meantime I found a solution:

Although GitHub Actions has no syntax for directly creating a Mappings/Objects it can be done indirectly with [fromJson()](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/expressions#fromjson):

```
${{ fromJson('{ 32: "i386", 64: "x86_64" }')[machine_architecture] }}
```

this fromJson() will create a mapping from int to string. the following []-operator resolves the int type "machine_architecture" to a string type.

Answer (score 2):

I don't need a matrix for this, but I need a map for lookups.

Couldn't get @PeterEvans answer to work with GitHub, so I adapted it slightly:

```yaml
jobs:
  yourJobName:
    name: Cool Job
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Get Machine Arc 
        run: |
          MACHINE_ARC_MAP=$(cat <<END
          {
            32: "i386", 
            64: "x86_64",
            999: ${{ secrets.SECRET_ARC }}
          }
          END
          )
          TARGET_ARC=$(echo $MACHINE_ARC_MAP | jq -r 'to_entries[] | select(.key=="${{ github.event.inputs.machine_architecture }}") | .value')
          echo "TARGET_ARC=$TARGET_ARC" >> $GITHUB_ENV
      
      - name: Echo Selected value
        run: |
          echo ${env.TARGET_VAR}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way to do it with JSON and jq. It creates the step output `${{ steps.vars.outputs.arch }}` which you can use in later steps.

```
jobs:
  varMap:
    strategy:
      matrix:
        machine_architecture: [32, 64]
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Set arch var
        id: vars
        run: |
          echo ::set-output name=arch::\
          $(echo '{ "32": "i386", "64": "x86_64" }' | jq -r 'to_entries[] | select(.key=="${{ matrix.machine_architecture }}") | .value')

      - name: Test arch var
        run: echo "Testing ${{ steps.vars.outputs.arch }}"
```

Comment: This solution is exactly what I linked in the "PS:" section of my question. But as I described there, I can use the vars only in the following steps and not outside the "steps:" section (i.e. in the "runs-on:" section)

Comment: In that case, I think what you are trying to do is, unfortunately, not possible at the moment. My understanding is that `runs-on` only has access to the [`matrix` context](https://help.github.com/en/actions/reference/contexts-and-expression-syntax-for-github-actions#contexts). Additionally, as far as I know, there are no ways to compute a value outside of a step.

Comment: Thanks for this, using a JSON file and jq proved nicer than trying to mix shell tests and github expression mini-language to convert matrix axis values to parameters needed by setup-* actions.  Only detail is that I find that `to_entries` complicates the data structure needlessly; `jq -r '.["${{ matrix.tox-env }}"]' < .github/workflows/mapping.json` is enough to get a value from a key :)

Answer (score 0):

How about your "map_object" is actually a file mapping `machine_architecture` values into the values you need, such:

```
32=i386
64=x86_64
```

or any other format you want to keep.

Then, your job can define it in a secondary variable as:

```
jobs:
  FirstJob:
    name: job 1
    runs-on: .....
    steps:
      - uses: ....
      - name: Define variables
        run: |
          cat $(cat MAP_OBJECT_FILE_NAME) | grep $(cat machine_architecture)= | > MACHINE_ARCHITECTURE_STRING
```

From there on, you would have the `MACHINE_ARCHITECTURE_STRING` variable available for the jobs you need. You could of course do it much more simple concatenating or whatever, but here you maintain the mapping in your code with the mapping file and is escalable.